# Python MySQLdb error when trying to alter a table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, syntax

I am trying to alter a database but I am not sure of the exact syntax and I am having trouble finding it online. The line that is giving the error is:

```
 cur.execute("ALTER TABLE Units ADD FOREIGN KEY(pnid), REFERENCES Basic(pnid)) ")
```

The error is

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' REFERENCES Basic(pnid))' at line 1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using correct syntax for adding a foreign key as docs says

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

You have an extra comma before `REFERENCES` remove it

```
ALTER TABLE Units ADD FOREIGN KEY(pnid) REFERENCES Basic(pnid));
```

[*Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma `,` before `REFERENCES` as seen below

```
ALTER TABLE Units ADD FOREIGN KEY(pnid), REFERENCES Basic(pnid) 
                                        <--Here
```

`ALTER` statement should look like

```
ALTER TABLE Units ADD FOREIGN KEY(pnid) REFERENCES Basic(pnid)
```